# Accelerometer to move player left and right

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

Please take a look on my code and help me to find problem.

I used this tutorial: [COCOS2D_ACCELEROMETER_MOVEMENT](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips%3ausing_accelerometer_for_sprite_movement)
This works only sometime….some time not move..How can I resolve this problem?
Here is my sample: [DOWNLOAD](http://www.4shared.com/zip/BUJJedIy/testAcc.html)
Thanks for reading this…what's wrong with my code ? Is there any other way?

Here is my code:

```
#define kHeroMovementAction 1
#define kPlayerSpeed 500
- (void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    // use the running scene to grab the appropriate game layer by it's tag

    // grab the player sprite from that layer using it's tag
    CCSprite *playerSprite = mPlayer;
    float destX, destY;
    BOOL shouldMove = NO;

    float currentX = playerSprite.position.x;
    float currentY = playerSprite.position.y;

    if(acceleration.x > 0.25) {  // tilting the device upwards
        destX = currentX - (acceleration.y * kPlayerSpeed);
        destY = currentY + (acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
        shouldMove = YES;
    } else if (acceleration.x < -0.25) {  // tilting the device downwards
        destX = currentX - (acceleration.y * kPlayerSpeed);
        destY = currentY + (acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
        shouldMove = YES;
    } else 

        if(acceleration.y < -0.25) {  // tilting the device to the right
        destX = currentX - (acceleration.y * kPlayerSpeed);
        destY = currentY + (acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
        shouldMove = YES;
    } else if (acceleration.y > 0.25) {  // tilting the device to the left
        destX = currentX - (acceleration.y * kPlayerSpeed);
        destY = currentY + (acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
        shouldMove = YES;
    } else {
        destX = currentX;
        destY = currentY;
    }

    if(shouldMove) 
    {
        CGSize wins = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        // ensure we aren't moving out of bounds     
        if(destX < 30 || destX > wins.width - 30 || destY < 30 || destY > wins.height - 100) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            CCAction *action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position: CGPointMake(destX, playerSprite.position.y)];
            [playerSprite stopActionByTag:kHeroMovementAction];
            [action setTag:kHeroMovementAction];
            [playerSprite runAction:action];
        }
    } else {
        // should stop
        [playerSprite stopActionByTag:kHeroMovementAction];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That method of moving a player left and right is a little bit complicated and can be done in a much much nicer way using a simpler class design.

Create a player class and declare `cgpoint vel` and `pos`. You will also want a CCSprite in the header file of this class:

```
@interface player : CCLayer 
{
    CCSprite *spriteName;
    CGPoint vel;
    CGPoint pos;
}

@end
```

In the class set `self.isAcelerometerEnabled = TRUE;` in the init method.

Then in the player class you want:

```
-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{   
    float deceleration = 0.1f, sensitivity = 8.0f, maxVelocity = 150;

    // adjust velocity based on current accelerometer acceleration
    vel.x = vel.x * deceleration + acceleration.x * sensitivity;

    //limit the maximum velocity of the player sprite, in both directions (positive & negative values)
    vel.x = fmaxf(fminf(vel.x, maxVelocity), -maxVelocity);
}
```

In your update method for the player class you want:

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    float imageWidthHalved = [boat texture].contentSize.width * 0.25f;
    float leftBorderLimit = imageWidthHalved + 45;
    float rightBorderLimit = screenSize.width - imageWidthHalved - 45;

    pos = spriteName.position;
    pos.x += vel.x;

    if (pos.x < leftBorderLimit)
    {
        pos.x = leftBorderLimit;
        vel = CGPointZero;
    }
    else if (pos.x > rightBorderLimit)
    {
        pos.x = rightBorderLimit;
        vel = CGPointZero;
    }

    spriteName.position = pos;
}
```

Then in your main world class init just call (assuming you have declared a player object in your header file and called it player):

```
player = [player node];
[self addChild:player z:2];
```

Hopefully this will be enough code to get you started, assuming you know how to create classes in cocos2d. Also in your player class dont forget to call:

```
[self scheduleUpdate];
```

In the init method in your player class.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lewis..this is what I need. Now working very smooth.